# .py config file with fallback data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, settings

I have a `settings.py` file in my project:

```
"Nickname of the user to check the games for"
USERNAME = "user"
```

Unfortunately, it will be overwritten by each upgrade. So, I'd like to allow the user to override the default settings by creating a `.py` file `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/myapp/config.py`, containing for example

```
USERNAME = "real-user"
```

Is it possible to modify `settings.py` so  that it sucks any variables from the `.../config.py` file in a generic way, something like including this file at the end of `config.py`?

I'm using Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the way you get the values from the `settings.py` file is by `import`ing it:

```
import settings

print(settings.USERNAME)
```

Then you could change it by adding something like this to the end which will do what you want.

**`settings.py`**

```
"Nickname of the user to check the games for"
USERNAME = "user"

def _read_overrides(filename):
    localdict = {}  # populated by exec
    try:
        with open(filename) as file:
            exec(compile(file.read(), filename, 'exec'),
                 {'__builtins__': None}, localdict)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    return localdict

for key, value in _read_overrides('config.py').items():
    globals()[key] = value
```

Then after it's `import`ed, the `print(settings.USERNAME)` will display:

```
real-user
```

Also note the `config.py` overrides file can be named anything (it's doesn't need a `.py` extension).

Comment: `execfile` is not defined in python3

Comment: Oops, sorry—see revised answer.

Comment: I didn't have time before, but yes, it does. Thanks a lot! I added the `try ... except` clause to catch the situation that `config.py` doesn't exist

Comment: marmistrz: Sure, if that how you want it handled. Generally I don't silently ignore exceptions unless that's explicitly what's specified in the question.

Comment: I thought a while about it... Isn't it a security vulnerability? One can put anything into `config.py`, not only variable defintions...

Comment: A `config.py` can have arbitrary Python code in it, but I attempted to mitigate that fact by making built-in identifiers unavailable via the defining of `__builtins__` as `None`. Many consider using `exec` on untrusted input an unacceptable security breach depending on the context of its usage. The same is true of `import`ing untrusted input. A safer alternative would be to use the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) module and a `.ini` file.

Comment: Some consider the third-party [`ConfigObj`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/configobj.shtml) module superior to `configparser`. You can download it from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/configobj/5.0.6).

Comment: Oh, `exec` is really dangerous. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html Consider adding this to your answer.